# SSRS make reports start from negative values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is possible to make a report start from a negative value?

I mean for example when a line chart or bar chart finds a value in a report it displays it from a specific negative value instead of 0.

[ssrs line chart starting from negative number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDOJb.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Axis properties of the Axis you want to start at a specific value and enter a value or an expression in the `Min` property. SO you could put in a a simple number e.g. -5 or you could make it dynamic, something like

```
=IIF(Sum(SalesAmount)<100, -30, 0)
```

If this is not what you are after, please provide more details.

Comment: I need to start the series value from that value not the scale only, as shown on the image the background fillment of the report should cover untill -3 not 0.

To make a simplest example as possible Imagine you want to rapresent a value that starts from -5 so for example a bar chart should start from -5 not 0, not the scale only